DIP or DIP like auto-bidirectional multi-voltage level translator
I am looking for an auto-bidirectional multi-voltage level translator for converting TTL and LVCMOS level signals.
I understand that the 3.3 signal coming from the LVCMOS system is safe for the TTL but I can say that in breadboard the 5v ttl signal fries the LVCMOS chip instantly.
I would rather use an auto-bidirectional level converter as a single IC instead of using two unidirectional converters OR only converting the 5v.
The project I am working on is for a robotic club for my school so keeping the package as DIP makes board assembly approachable and interesting for all students as they like to solder. I would rather avoid having to hot plate or micro-solder joints as its beyond the skillset of some students. Otherwise I would absolutely use one of the abundant sop/tsop packages available from Texas instruments or others.

most low voltage cmos can handle 5.5v from TTL without issue : eg 77lvc00

SOP and SOIC parts are actually easier to solder  with a soldering iron as unlike DIP you don't need to flip the board over.

What is your question. This is a question and answer site so...

If your intention is to buy DIP ICs that do bidirectional level shifting, unfortunately I'm not aware of any (and a search didn't turn up anything either.) They're all SOIC or smaller.
Anyway, a FET, properly biased, can do bidirectional level shifting. You can buy FET-based shifters pre-made from Sparkfun, Adafruit, etc.
Here's a sim to show how FET shifters work (simulate it here):

FET-based shifters exploit FET Vgs threshold. When the 5V side goes above 5V-Vgs, or 3.5V, the FET pinches off.
The FET type used is the common 2N7002, BSS138 or similar. These are available in SOT-23. If you have a decent soldering iron mounting SOT-23 isn't so difficult. Solder cream and a small heat gun can do it too.
There is also the older 2N7000 which is TO-92. That might be an option if you're 100% opposed to SMT.
Beyond this there's breakout boards with level shifter ICs mounted on them, again at Sparkfun and Adafruit.

A DIP resistor network with 8 separate 1 kOhm resistors, placed in series with each line, will work sufficiently well. It doesn't convert the voltage, but it limits the current. It would not be ideal in a product, but it's simple, effective, and DIP.
For example: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/bourns-inc/4116R-1-102LF/1088609

This works only if the LVCMOS device has clamping diodes to VCC.

@CL They do.   4 more to go...
